# loops with data from a matrix

Tags: r

i have a database that i have concentrate in a matrix called DB as follow:

```
         PN        time.state.2 STATUS
   [1,] 6954010001            0    3.0
   [2,] 6954010001            3    3.5
   [3,] 6954010001            6    3.5
   [4,] 6954010001            9    3.5
   [5,] 6954010001           12    3.5
```

in which there are many subjects and for each of them more than one row is registered (are different visits of patients for which a STATUS is registered).

I would like create a for loop that create an object called "progression" if the same patient increase own value of STATUS in subsequent visits.

I don't understand how to assign to index "i" the PN code of the patients to permit that when finish with a patient go to the further.

For example for one patient with these SCORE values at each time-point highlighted by time.state.2 object i would like that patient is considered PROGRESSED when his SCORE value increase of 1-point compared with the first timepoint of that patient (first visit in hospital). Further this PROGRESSION has to be confirmed in the subsequent visit (for this patient at time 6 STATUS reach 4.0 (1-point higher than the first visit which was 3.0) and this value is confirmed in the subsequent visit so the PROGRESSION is confirmed.)

```
         PN        time.state.2 STATUS  PROGRESSION
   [1,] 6954010001            0    3.0            0
   [2,] 6954010001            3    3.5            0
   [3,] 6954010001            6    4.0            1
   [4,] 6954010001            9    4.0            0
   [5,] 6954010001           12    4.5            0
   [6,] 6954010001           15    4.5            0
```

I would like also that PROGRESSION for each patient is 1 only the first time and possibly drop (for that patient) the subsequent visits after his progression.
For example:

```
         PN        time.state.2 STATUS  PROGRESSION
   [1,] 6954010001            0    3.0            0
   [2,] 6954010001            3    3.5            0
   [3,] 6954010001            6    4.0            1
   [4,] 6954010002            0    6.0            0
   [5,] 6954010002            3    6.0            0
```

when the first patient stop when PROGRESSION=1.

Comment: You should add some expected output and [what you have already tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), as it is not entirely clear at present. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this:

```
#create data
DF <- read.table(text="         PN        time.state.2 STATUS
   [1,] 6954010001            0    3.0
   [2,] 6954010001            3    3.5
   [3,] 6954010001            6    3.5
   [4,] 6954010001            9    3.5
   [5,] 6954010001           12    3.5
   [6,] 6954010002            0    3.0
   [7,] 6954010002            3    3.0
   [8,] 6954010002            6    3.5
   [9,] 6954010002            9    3.5
   [10,] 6954010002          12    3.5",header=TRUE)

#you claim to have a matrix
m <- as.matrix(DF)

#turn the matrix into a data.frame
DF <- as.data.frame(m)
rownames(DF) <- NULL

#use package plyr to split according to patient, 
#apply function, and combine back
library(plyr)
#calculate the cumulative sum of differences in STATUS
#put a 0 in front, since there can be no progress at the first time point
DF <- ddply(DF,.(PN),transform,progress=c(0,cumsum(diff(STATUS))))

print(DF)
#            PN time.state.2 STATUS progress
# 1  6954010001            0    3.0      0.0
# 2  6954010001            3    3.5      0.5
# 3  6954010001            6    3.5      0.5
# 4  6954010001            9    3.5      0.5
# 5  6954010001           12    3.5      0.5
# 6  6954010002            0    3.0      0.0
# 7  6954010002            3    3.0      0.0
# 8  6954010002            6    3.5      0.5
# 9  6954010002            9    3.5      0.5
# 10 6954010002           12    3.5      0.5
```

---

## Edit after clarification:

```
DF <- read.table(text="         PN        time.state.2 STATUS
[1,] 6954010001            0    3.0
[2,] 6954010001            3    3.5
[3,] 6954010001            6    4.0
[4,] 6954010001            9    3.5
[5,] 6954010001           12    6.0
[6,] 6954010002            0    3.0
[7,] 6954010002            3    4.0
[8,] 6954010002            6    4.0
[9,] 6954010002            9    6.0
[10,] 6954010002          12    6.0",header=TRUE)

rownames(DF) <- NULL

DF <- ddply(DF,.(PN),transform,progress=(STATUS-STATUS[1])>=1 & 
                                        (c(STATUS[-1],FALSE)-STATUS[1])>=1)

DF <- ddply(DF,.(PN),function(x) {x$progress[x$progress][-1] <- FALSE; x})

#            PN time.state.2 STATUS progress
# 1  6954010001            0    3.0    FALSE
# 2  6954010001            3    3.5    FALSE
# 3  6954010001            6    4.0    FALSE
# 4  6954010001            9    3.5    FALSE
# 5  6954010001           12    6.0    FALSE
# 6  6954010002            0    3.0    FALSE
# 7  6954010002            3    4.0     TRUE
# 8  6954010002            6    4.0    FALSE
# 9  6954010002            9    6.0    FALSE
# 10 6954010002           12    6.0    FALSE
```

Comment: If your database is huge and the plyr solution too slow, I can add a solution using package data.table, which is more efficient, but uses a special syntax and might be harder to grasp for you.

Comment: +1 I hope you don't mind but I went ahead and did a data.table solution anyway, using your `cumsum` method. I also put in another solution for a different possible outcomes because I cannot be sure what output the OP is expecting (no guarantees it is yet right I suppose).

Comment: @Ale come on! Roland's taken the time to work through your problem extensively, and come up with a great solution that does exactly what you want. You should really consider accepting this as the answer (without obligation of course) or describe in detail why this is insufficient. Marking an answered as accepted means it no longer appears on the unanswered questions list.